# testing convergence of given series and finding its limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

let me know if I am correct? - to check convergence and find limit
If not please correct me, also another method to solve is very welcome.

For given series 
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(\log(n+i)-\log{n})^2}{n+1}$$

To test its convergence,
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(\log(n+i)-\log{n})^2}{n+1} =\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(\log(1+\frac{i}{n}))^2}{n+1}$$

$$ \implies S_n \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(\frac{i}{n})^2}{n+1}$$

$$ \implies S_n \leq \frac{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}}{n^2(n+1)}$$

$$ \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}}{n^2(n+1)}$$

$$ \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n \leq \frac{1}{3}$$

Thus limit converges

To find the limit of sum, I changes sum into reimann sum

$$S_n  =\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(\log(1+\frac{i}{n}))^2}{n+1}$$

$$ \implies S_n  =\int_{1}^{2} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n+1}(\log(1+x))^2$$

$$ \implies S_n  =\int_{1}^{2} (\log(1+x))^2$$

Using Integration by parts

$$ \implies S_n  =2(\log2)^2-2\log2+1 $$

Comment: $$ 0.5746\approx2(\log2)^2-2\log2+1\,\color{red}{\gt}\,\frac{1}{3}=0.3333 \\ \int_{1}^{2}\log^2(1+x)\,\color{red}{=}\,1-2\left(1-\log(2)\right)^2+3\left(1-\log(3)\right)^2\,\,\approx0.841 $$

Comment: The first (correct) part $\{S_n\le1/3\}$, only shows an upper bound and not sufficient to prove convergent

Comment: Sum is increasing and bounded above so convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong integral.

$S_n \to \int_0^1 \log^2(1 + x) dx 
= 2 (\log(2) - 1)^2≈0.18832
$.

You took $1+x$ into account twice instead of once.

This now agrees with
your upper bound.